# Memory management regarding CATransition's delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAAnimation/delegate):

> Important: The delegate object is retained by the receiver. This is a rare exception to the memory management rules described in Memory Management Programming Guide.

Right now, I'm setting the delegate and not releasing it, which is what I'd normally do.

When I set the delegate of a CATransition object, am I leaking the delegate by not releasing it? I've tried this method and it crashed my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. I think the documentation is just saying that the receiver is retaining the delegate internally, which means it also has the responsibility to release it internally. Imo, you should not be doing an extra release.

Comment: correct.  if the transition ("the receiver") is retaining its delegate, then it will also release it.  If you find that this is not the case, file a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I was just confused by this statement in the docs. Makes me wonder why they put it in there in the first place.

Comment: It is there to let you know that you can safely release your delegate even if the CATransition still exists, and nothing will break.